# How do you access the environment variables stored in the local.settings.json while running tests on azure cloud functions written in nodejs?

Tags: sql, function, api, cloud, azure-cosmosdb

I can access them while building the functions for local testing but it seems to be not picking up the environment variables when I run mocha tests on the cloud functions[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta3zw.png)